# Find duplicate in List(Of T) using LINQ VB .NET not working

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a generic `List(Of T)` with a bunch of items that contain some duplicate values at `.ItemID`. I need the code to return only the duplicates, but my code below returns all of the items.

```
Dim items As List(Of ItemsClass.ItemCollection) = _
        New List(Of ItemsClass.ItemCollection)(oleObj.ListOfItemsToCopy(listViewItems)) 'Returns a list of items

Dim duplicates = From c In items Where (c.ItemID.Count > 1) Select c 'Needs to return duplicate items
```

---

An example of the `List(Of ItemCollection)` items are as follows

```
ItemID, Make,     Type     Year
123456  Ford      Falcon   1999
123457  Mazda     CX6      2001
123456  Ford      Ranger   2002
```

I need to group the `ItemID` and return all of the duplicate results

Comment: Do you need to return all of the duplicates or just one of each duplicate item? (Because each item with the same ID would have the same values, right?)

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to return all of the duplicate ItemID's as they contain different values.

Comment: Does that then point to an underlying issue with `ItemID` values being re-used?

Comment: I will edit initial post and add some values to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested, the following worked well for me

```
Public Class Form1
Private Class ItemsCollection
    Private _name As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _data As String
    Public Property data() As String
        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _data = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim items As List(Of ItemsCollection) = New List(Of ItemsCollection)()

    items.Add(New ItemsCollection With {.name = "Test", .data = "Test2"})
    items.Add(New ItemsCollection With {.name = "Test1", .data = "Test2"})
    items.Add(New ItemsCollection With {.name = "Test3", .data = "Test4"})

    For Each item As ItemsCollection In items.GroupBy(Function(x) x.data).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).SelectMany(Function(x) x)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.name + " " + item.data)
    Next

 End Sub
End Class
```

**Output**

```
Test Test2
Test1 Test2
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is come C# syntax for this it *shows the operations* for a general method to detect duplicates in LINQ, but it will need to be converted to VB.NET syntax as appropriate.

The code also takes the liberty to define `T` as "a type for a *single* item that has an ItemID property"; I am unsure why/how the ItemCollection type fits in.

```cs
IEnumerable<T> items = ..;

// Group the items
var groupsById = items.GroupBy(i => i.ItemID);

// Find the groups with more than one item
// (The items in the resulting groups are duplicates of each other)
var groupsWithDups = groupsById.Where(g => g.Length > 1);

// If the source is [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2] the output will
// contain the following [1, 1, 2, 2, 2].
IEnumerable<T> allDups = groupsWithDups.SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: Please don't comment if you don't know the answer. I need the proper syntax for VB. I know how to do this in C#, but I need to know in VB, particularly the syntax. And yes, I see the mistake I made by not grouping.

Comment: The VB syntax should not be dramatically different.  In all likelihood, it is a straight transcoding.

Comment: `List<string> duplicateItemsList = new List<string>(rddsPathList.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1))
.Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList());`  This is how i would do it in C#

Comment: @TonyMontana: `Dim duplicateItemsList As New List(Of String)(rddsPathList.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)).Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1).[Select](Function(x) x.Key).ToList())`, according to http://converter.telerik.com/ and http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Lamba parameter 'x' hides a variable in an enclosing block.

Comment: @RobertHarvey your last comment is not very constructive buddy. If I knew VB syntax (or how to "fix it") I wouldn't be here asking for help.

Comment: Anyway, according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763158(v=vs.90).aspx), you need unique names for each lambda variable (this is not true of C#).  So the updated code reads `Dim duplicateItemsList As New List(Of String)(rddsPathList.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)).Where(Function(y) y.Count() > 1).[Select](Function(z) z.Key).ToList())`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You're a saint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if it were up to me, I would have developed the system in C#, but unfortunately it has already been built in VB, so I need to maintain it in VB. The LINQ syntax is something I have yet to learn in VB. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TonyMontana Ref. [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)